# Pandas DataFrame to csv: Specifying decimal separator for mixed type

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I've found a somewhat strange behaviour when I create a Pandas DataFrame from lists and convert it to csv with a specific decimal separator.

This works as expected:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> a = pd.DataFrame([['a', 0.1], ['b', 0.2]])
>>> a
   0    1
0  a  0.1
1  b  0.2
>>> a.to_csv(decimal=',', sep=' ')
' 0 1\n0 a 0,1\n1 b 0,2\n'
```

However, in this case the decimal separator is not set properly:

```
>>> b = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], [0.1, 0.2]])
>>> b
     0    1
0    a    b
1  0.1  0.2
>>> b.to_csv(decimal=',', sep=' ')
' 0 1\n0 a b\n1 0.1 0.2\n'
```

When I transpose `b` in order to get a DataFrame like `a` the decimal separator is still not properly set:

```
>>> b.T.to_csv(decimal=',', sep=' ')
' 0 1\n0 a 0.1\n1 b 0.2\n'
```

Why I am asking: In my program I have columns as individual lists (e.g. `col1 = ['a', 'b']` and `col2 = [0.1, 0.2]`, but the number and format of columns can vary) and I would like to convert them to csv with a specific decimal separator, so I'd like to have an output like

```
' 0 1\n0 a 0,1\n1 b 0,2\n'
```

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?  decimal was only added in 0.16 onwards

Comment: @NickHale I use 0.18.1

Answer (score 2):

Use [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) and cast the `float` typed cells to `str` by checking explicitly for their type. Then, replace the decimal dot`(.)` with the comma `(,)` as each cell now constitutes a string and dump the contents to a `csv` file later.

```
b.applymap(lambda x: str(x).replace(".", ",") if isinstance(x, float) else x).to_csv(sep=" ")
# ' 0 1\n0 a b\n1 0,1 0,2\n'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd see this more as a last resort when there is no other way, because my string columns can also contain dots (one of the string columns contains file names), which would also be converted.

Comment: Since their types are most likely being interspersed with one another, this is a safe option to consider.